# Laravel: multiple image upload issue(in REST api) with curl and postman

Tags: php, laravel, rest, curl, postman

Uploading multiple images in larvel rest api from postman/curl are not able work.
It only insert one image.

Using larvel upload form in view has no issue at all, it work fine.

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple />
```

WHat i am trying is to upload multiple images with Postman and curl in Laravel rest api.

THis is controller file

```
public function uploadimages(Request $request){
            $files = $request->allFiles('image');       
            $count = 0;       
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file->store('public/uploads');
                $count++;
                //this technic also not work
                /* $name= $file->getClientOriginalName();
                   $file->move('public/uploads', $name);
                   $images[]=$name;*/
           }
           //$count return only 1(it only upload one file)
           return response()->json($count, 201);
    }
```

This is my curl command

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:8000/api/uploadimages -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "image=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\2.jpg" -F "image=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\1.jpg"
```

this command insert only one file.

i also put this and tried "image[]=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\1.jpg" and get the error.

```
 curl -X POST  http://localhost:8000/api/uploadimages -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "image[]=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\2.jpg" -F "image[]=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\1.jpg"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (26) couldn't open file "/C:\xampp\htdocs\2.jpg"
```

In postman application also only upload one file.
i double check about postman setting for uploading file from other question. i think setting is ok.

i cant find uploading multiple images in Larvel Rest api.

What is the issue there, please somebody suggest me and explain me about the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're trying to send 2 files with the same key.  `image` in this case. Try changing second file key to something else like `image2` so it would be something like

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:8000/api/uploadimages -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "image=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\2.jpg" -F "image2=@/C:\xampp\htdocs\1.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks @avpav, it worked. i hav been stuck for many day. You help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: one thing, do you have any idea suggestion why is it not working in postman application?

Comment: I don't know. Can you provide a screenshot?